# FFMPEG Video Concat and Overlay

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I want to combine two `ffmpeg` commands to a single command. I am using ready made `ffmpeg` binary in my Android application. I want to concat `.ts` files and overlay an image.

I am using following commands:

1. To concat `.ts` files:

   ```
   String[] ffmpegcommand = {"ffmpeg", "-i","concat:"+input_file_path+"|"+input_file_path1, "-c", "copy", "-bsf:a", "aac_adtstoasc", output_file_path};
   ```
2. Apply image overlay effect:

   ```
   String[] ffmpegcommand = {"ffmpeg","-y" ,"-i", input_file_path,"-strict","experimental", "-vf","movie="+AppStaticData.BASE_FOLDER_PATH + File.separator + "watermarklogo.png"+" [watermark]; [in][watermark] overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:10 [out]", AppStaticData.BASE_FOLDER_PATH+"/" + output_file_path};
   ```

Comment: I am not familiar with android. But to concat .ts files on linux you can simply "cat" them like text files. In linux i would pipe the catted file to the ffmpeg command.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this in one command with the [concat filter](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#concat):

```
ffmpeg -i input0.ts -i input1.ts -i input2.ts -i overlay.png -filter_complex \
"[0:v][0:a][1:v][1:a][2:v][2:a]concat=n=3:v=1:a=1[vv][a]; \
 [vv][3:v]overlay=W-w-10:10[v]" \
-map "[v]" -map "[a]" output.mp4
```

- Use `-filter_complex` instead of `-vf`. See the [documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Filtering) for an explanation of the difference. Also, you don't need the `movie` source filter.
- This will place the overlay in the top right with 10px padding. See [examples of other placement locations](https://superuser.com/a/939386/110524) and read the [overlay filter documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay) for more info.

Comment: Whenever I used the concat filter, I never had to use the `setpts` filter to reset the timestamps. Let's say you're segmenting into `.ts` files using the `segment` muxer, then the TS files will have non-zero start times, e.g. the first frame in the second TS file may have a PTS of `12.4`, but the concatenation will still work. Wondering in which cases it's strictly required. We may need to update the wiki entry, too.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard, I added the suggestion from  Areeb Soo Yasir.  It looks like the same command, but you might want to verify.

Comment: @fixer1234 Thanks, but I think the actual issue is that I forgot to add a backslash to some of the lines in my command. Either that or he is using Windows which I believe would require a `^` instead, or more typically Windows users make it into one line. The line breaks are just for readability. I'll fix it and it should work fine as is (for Linux and macOS).

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to LordNeckbeard just one thing is that you may think his solution doesn't work because if you copy and paste everything will not work.  Just put it all as one line and it will work like so:

```
ffmpeg -i file1.mp4 -i file2.mp4 -i file3.mp4 -i watermark.png -filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v0]; [1:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v1]; [2:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v2]; [v0][0:a][v1][1:a][v2][2:a]concat=n=3:v=1:a=1[v][aout]; [v][3:v]overlay=W-w-10:10[vout]" -map "[vout]" -map "[aout]" output.mp4
```

Comment: The intention is for each answer to provide a complete solution that is different from what has already been contributed.  This is really, commentary or suggested improvement to another post.  You're a little short of the rep needed to comment, but you could suggest this as an edit to the other answer.

Comment: Hi there fixer yes good point if LordNeckBeard can update his I am happy to remove this answer.  It is just that as silly as it sounds I think it's a bit unusable as he has posted it and produces errors from ffmpeg which led me to initially believe the answer was not working, thus the actual full working command above.

Comment: I added it to LordNeckbeard's answer.  You might want to wait a day or two to see if he agrees with the edit before deleting your answer.

Comment: @AreebSooYasir I forgot to add some missing backslashes in my answer. I often break up the command into multiple lines for readability and so users can more easily understand how the FFmpeg filtergraphs are constructed. Users can re-construct it into a single line if desired (and Windows users will be required to do so, or I think they can replace the backslash with a caret [`^`]).