# How to position drawtext text

Tags: ffmpeg, watermark

I'm trying to create a video using ffmpeg but I can't get the text watermark on the bottom right corner. It appears on the middle of the video. How should I change the following command?

```
-vf drawtext="fontfile=C\\:/Windows/Fonts/Arial.ttf: \
text='Stack Overflow': fontcolor=white: fontsize=24: box=1: boxcolor=black: \
x=(w-text_w)/2: y=(h-text_h-line_h)/2"
```

Answer (score 45):

## Positions

- Top left: `x=0:y=0` (with 10 pixel padding `x=10:y=10`)
- Top center: `x=(w-text_w)/2:y=0` (with 10 px padding `x=(w-text_w)/2:y=10`)
- Top right: `x=w-tw:y=0` (with 10 px padding: `x=w-tw-10:y=10`)
- Centered: `x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/2`
- Bottom left: `x=0:y=h-th` (with 10 px padding: `x=10:y=h-th-10`)
- Bottom center: `x=(w-text_w)/2:y=h-th` (with 10 px padding: `x=(w-text_w)/2:y=h-th-10`)
- Bottom right: `x=w-tw:y=h-th` (with 10 px padding: `x=w-tw-10:y=h-th-10`)

## Full example (centered)

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "drawtext=text='Super User':x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/2:fontsize=24:fontcolor=white" -c:a copy output.mp4
```

See [drawtext filter documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#drawtext) for more info.

Comment: can we dynamically change text before recording each frame?

Comment: @user924 The text position or the text content?

Comment: Text content. I want to record timestamp (yyyy-mm-dd  hh-mm-ss)

Comment: @user924 See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/575935/110524).

Comment: Thanks, @LordNeckbeard in person for helping me for most of my ffmpeg related queries. Have a great day!

Comment: Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument `-filter_complex "pad=height=ih-40:color=#71cbf4,overlay=x=w-tw-10:y=h-th-10"`

Comment: @JamieHutber There are too many things wrong with your command to fix it in a comment. You should make a new question. Make sure to show your full command and also include the complete log from the command.

Comment: Thanks very much Logan for the very fast reply. I have managed to get it into the top right `overlay=x=(main_w-overlay_w)-30:y=(main_h-overlay_h)/(main_h-overlay_h)+30` I will raise a quesiton now

Comment: Thank you, but you actually missed the one I wanted, bottom center ;)

Comment: You Rock! Thank you!