# How do I add a combine a .mp3 and image in ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-conversion

So I am trying to combine a .mp3 and a image and add text then turn it into a .mp4 with ffmpeg, what would the command for this be.

I tried: `ffmpeg -i audio.mp3 -i background.jpg -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]overlay=10:10,drawtext=text='Hello World'" -c:a copy -movflags +faststart output.mp4`

But it gave me this error: `Stream specifier ':v' in filtergraph description [0:v][1:v]overlay=10:10,drawtext=text='Hello World' matches no streams.`

Also how would I change the font of the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to use overlay. Just use the image as the input to the [drawtext filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#drawtext):

```
ffmpeg -i audio.mp3 -loop 1 -framerate 10 -i background.jpg -filter_complex "[1:v]drawtext=text='Hello World':fontfile=/path/to/your/font.ttf:fontsize=24:fontcolor=white:x=10:y=10,format=yuv420p[v]" -map "[v]" -map 0:a -c:a copy -movflags +faststart -shortest output.mp4
```

Other changes:

- The image must be looped, so the `-loop 1` input option was added. Because it loops indefinitely the `-shortest` output option was also added so the file stops when the audio stops.
- Added `-framerate 10` to set image frame rate. Default is 25. Using a lower fps than 10 risks causing problems with some players.
- Select font with `fontfile` option.
- See [How to position drawtext text](https://superuser.com/a/939386/) for examples for `x` and `y` positions.
- Added the format filter to set yuv420p pixel format for compatibility.
- Consider changing `-c:a copy` to `-c:a aac` for compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with ffmpeg but I think you should do this in the following order:

1. Convert mp3 into mp4
2. Add image
3. Add text

Mp3 is a audio format thats why I think you can't add text (so it appears like a video).
Of course you can edit the ID3-Tags.